# "npm start" command not working while launching Enketo

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

I have done enketo-express installtion while launching enkto it shows below error. I'm using this command to launch enketo "npm start"

`AbortError: Ready check failed: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (enketo-express/node_modules/redis/index.js:362:23)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (enketo-express/node_modules/redis/index.js:664:14)
    at Socket. (enketo-express/node_modules/redis/index.js:293:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Worker 7873 sadly passed away. It will be reincarnated.`

Note: Following [this doc](https://blog.enketo.org/install-enketo-production-ubuntu/) step no: 7

Answer (score 0):

check netstat -ntlp
which port is using 8005

or in some case something running on port 6380

```
"cache": {
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": "6379", # change port from 6380
"password": null
}
```

Also Different Node version too causes similar problems. Use node version as described in readme
`https://github.com/kobotoolbox/enketo-express/issues/528`